# пропали стили в админ панели wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Сайт сделан на elementor. Сайт отлично работает, но в админ панели wp пропали стили, голая разметка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: смотрите в инспекторе браузера ошибки

Answer (score 0):

- Через браузер открыть консоль разработчика/исходный код и посмотреть грузятся ли вообще эти стили (ошибка в коде, доступ к файлам веб серверу, блокировка расширениями барузера)
- Убедится в том, что браузеру не назначена установка на использование своего стиля (попробуйте другой браузер)
- сбросить кэш?

Answer (score 0):

в консоли была ошибка 403.
Переименовал файл htaccess и заработало